# How to return a compound literal struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a function that will always return a struct with known values.  What is the syntax?

```
struct MyStruct Function(void)
{
    return (struct MyStruct){1,2,3};
}
```

I am getting a compiler error on the return line:
Error: syntax error

Any ideas?  I'm using a cross-compiler to an embedded target, so it could be my compiler.

---

Edit
It's my compiler.  As cnicutar commented, it's valid C99 code.

Some people pointed out that I could create a variable.  My goal was to avoid creating a variable just to return it.

Comment: It's the compiler. C99 supports this perfectly.

Comment: How about C++ ? (GCC C++? Is there a switch?)

Comment: @imacake Question is about C, but I suppose G++ supports it by default?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're trying to cast a initializer as a struct :-)

<strike>This is not valid syntax.</strike> Try something like:

```
struct MyStruct Function(void)
{
    struct MyStruct s = {1,2,3};
    return s;
}
```

But it would be better to show how exactly `MyStruct` is declared, just in case.

Comment: No, the OP isn't casting anything but returning a compound literal. But this is a C99 feature which apparently isn't ubiquitous.

Comment: @cnicutar I was just kidding. How can I put a line over my text? I want to scratch out the part where I say about the syntax being invalid. C99 tricks me.

Comment: Thanks @cnicutar . Strike, that's the tag. I doubt I'll ever learn all about C99. Such strange facts, like `char arr[*]` in parameters, or this one… Maybe we should create a community-wiki post to reunite these.

Comment: @cnicutar it is my experience that compilers that advertise support for C99 support compound litterals.  I suspect the problem is that OPs compiler only suports C89(or some dialect thereof), as many compilers targeting embeded devices are want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way would be to create a variable of the appropriate type:

```
struct MyStruct Function(void) { 
    struct MyStruct ret = {1,2,3};
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another apporach would be create a struct constructor function like:

```c
struct MyStruct newMyStruct(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    struct myStruct;
    myStruct.a = arg1;
    // ...
    return myStruct;
}
```

Now, in functions you can return `newMyStruct(1, 2, 3)`, one line of code